# Why does discovery's replicator comment on people's meals?

Tags: star-trek

I'm not too far in to the series at the moment, but so far every time someone has ordered something on the replicator it tells them about its nutritional properties.  Why would it do this?

Comment: Perhaps it's a commentary on laws that are forcing restaurants to disclose the nutritional information of their meals?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Same reason restaurants and food you buy is labeled with that same information: to let you know what you're going to eat.

Given that this doesn't happen with replicators later, one imagines this was a thing that was in vogue for a while (like the holographic communication system) until people got annoyed with it.

Comment: fads come and go